# Kafka Schema registry internal consumer groups are not visible

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

When Schema registry initializes it creates two internal consumer groups

1. kafkastore.group.id

   `public static final String KAFKASTORE_GROUP_ID_CONFIG = "kafkastore.group.id";`
2. schema-registry.group.id

   `public static final String SCHEMAREGISTRY_GROUP_ID_CONFIG = "schema.registry.group.id";`

But these consumer groups are not being listed through this command.

`kafka-consumer-groups.sh --group "schema-registry" --describe --state --verbose`

Answer (score 0):

The Schema Registry doesn't use a consumer group since it doesn't need to store any offsets.

It always seeks to the beginning of the schemas topic, and reads to the end to populate its internal cache, and never commits.

`schema.registry.group.id` is used for clustering between highly available instances, rather than the consumer API